# Binary serialization of JSON or any plain-text using C

Tags: c, serialization, binary

I'd like to take plain ASCII text, such as JSON, and serialize it to be transferred over the wire in binary. I'd like to add an unsigned 4-byte header to this binary that will have the size of the JSON "object" to make it easier to deserialize on the server.

In PHP this would be done using the pack() and unpack() family of methods. I'd like to be able to do the same using ANSI C.

Comment: do you want to send the 32bit number in binary form? or in ascii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the json string, you don't need to convert to anything. Just prepend the length and send it.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is already a serialized format. And although you COULD go through the pain of converting it to binary, frankly there's not much of a point. Unless you're talking about a LOT of data (or an incredibly slow transfer speed), the benefits of converting it are minimal. As for prepending the length, even this isn't entirely necessary (although I know on the receiver side it IS nice to know how much memory to allocate up front). You could just as easily use a null terminator to indicate the end.